# How center several buttons in groupBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, alignment

I need a way to make center several buttons in a group box in WPF(C#) (Vertically and/or horizontally).

I used stackPanel but my buttons stick together :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap all the button in grid or stackpanel and set there alignment properties like this..

```
  <Grid>

        <GroupBox Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="LightGray">
            <GroupBox.Header>
                Mindcracker Network
            </GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="hello1" Width="100" Margin="5" />
            <Button Content="hello2" Width="100" Margin="5" />
            <Button Content="hello3" Width="100" Margin="5" />
            <Button Content="hello4" Width="100" Margin="5" />
        </StackPanel>


    </GroupBox>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but my buttons stick together... How can I fix it?